# Why index of hashcode is calculated in HashMap

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I was checking implementation of `HashMap` and in its `put` I see the after calculating the hash, index of the hash is calculated, like this `int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);`, and it is used as index of the underlying map.

```
/**
 * Returns index for hash code h.
 */
static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
    return h & (length-1);
}
```

I searched didn't find any explanation to my question that why again index of the hash is calculated which is used as final index of the underlying data structure. What is the advantage of it over using the hash as index.

I know it is nothing but bitwise AND but I want to know why it is done like this.

Comment: because you need the hash value mod the number of buckets! [0, n-1]

Comment: So this is like modulus? I means `h % (length -1)`

Comment: @pjj Yes, if `length` is a power-of-two. For instance, if `length` is 8 then the lower 3 bits provides the modulus (8 - 1 = 7 = 0111).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An object's hash code can be any `int` value, between -2^31 and 2^31-1. The underlying array used by a hash table is not going to have the same range (no negatives, for one, and likely not that large), therefore there must be some operation transforming the hash code from its original range to one between 0 and the array's length.

Because `HashMap` always uses arrays sized to a power of 2 (e.g. 16, 32, 64, etc.) using `&` is an efficient way to map hash codes to indicies, as it simply strips the other bits. Other hash table implementations might use modulo to similar effect, if they don't limit their array sizes to powers of two.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `int hash = hash(key.hashCode());` may return some value which is more than array's length or is it that it will always return value smaller than array's length? From your answer what I understood is this would be smaller/

Comment: @pjj The internal `hash()` method serves an entirely different purpose, which is to attempt to minimize hash collisions of certain types of hash values. Please ignore that call for the purpose of your question. --- For your question, `hashCode()` can return integer in full range of `int`, but hash table only has X buckets. To "map" hash code to a bucket, you'd calculate `hashCode() % X` to produce a valid bucket number (using *unsigned* integer math). Since X is always a power of 2, the slow `%` modulus operator can be replaced with the much faster bitwise `&` operator.

Comment: @pjj - I was describing how hash tables work in general, and how `HashMap` works in practice. There are *a lot* of additional implementation details (such as [`HashMap.hash()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l320)) that aren't as important as the general principles. If you're curious about `HashMap.hash()` in particular the comments in the source explains its purpose. As Andreas says, it's not relevant to your original question.